# Cannot catch Laravel 4 exception

Tags: php, laravel-4

I'm trying to catch a Laravel exception inside my library.

```
namespace Marsvin\Output\JoomlaZoo;

class Compiler
{

    protected function compileItem($itemId, $item)
    {
        $boom = explode('_', $itemId);
        $boom[0][0] = strtoupper($boom[0][0]);
        $className = __NAMESPACE__."\\Compiler\\".$boom[0];

        try {
            $class = new $className(); // <-- This is line 38
        } catch(\Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException $e) {
            throw new \Exception('I\'m not being thrown!');
        }
    }
}
```

This it the exception I'm getting:

```
file: "C:\MAMP\htdocs\name\app\libraries\WebName\Output\JoomlaZoo\Compiler.php"
line: 38
message: "Class 'Marsvin\Output\JoomlaZoo\Compiler\Deas' not found"
type: "Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException"
```

The name of the class is voluntarily wrong.

**Edit 1:**

I noticed that if I throw an exception inside the `try` statement I can catch the exception:

```
try {
    throw new \Exception('I\'d like to be thrown!');
} catch(\Exception $e) {
    throw new \Exception('I\'m overriding the previous exception!'); // This is being thrown
}
```

Comment: Quick check: Do a `catch(\Exception $e){ throw new \Exception("The exception thrown was a ".get_class($e); }`, so you know if it's actually the right one you're trying to catch.

Comment: Also you have a syntax error `throw new \Exception('I'm not being thrown!');` the quote inside the string should be escaped or use double quotes. But this might just be a problem with the example.

Comment: @Wrikken I tried that but I still get the Symphony's `FatalErrorException`. I'll add the output to the question.

Comment: @Bogdan You're right, but that's not the problem.

Comment: Hm, weird, what if you try to catch the `\ErrorException`?

Comment: That doesn't work either.

Comment: Use **Throwable** class instead *Exception* class. Look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46918345/2291935)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're trying to catch a `FatalErrorException` in your class, but Laravel won't let a fatal error get back there; it terminates immediately. If your were trying to catch a different kind of exception, your code would work just fine.

You can catch and handle fatal errors with an [`App::fatal` method](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/errors#handling-errors) in `app/start/global.php`, but that won't help you deal with the exception from within your library, or to handle it with any specificity. A better option would be to trigger a "catchable" exception (something from `Illuminate`, for instance), or to throw a custom one based on the condition that you are trying to check.

In your case, if your goal is to deal with undefined classes, here's what I would suggest:

```
try {
    $className = 'BadClass';
    if (!class_exists($className)) {
        throw new \Exception('The class '.$className.' does not exist.');
    }
    // everything was A-OK...
    $class = new $className();
} catch( Exception $e) {
    // handle the error, and/or throw different exception
    throw new \Exception($e->getMessage());
}
```