# Can't catch symfony FatalErrorException

Tags: php, symfony, exception

I have code like this:

```
try {
    $var = $object->getCollection()->first()->getItem()->getName();
} catch(\Exception $e) {
    $var = null;
}
```

Of course i have communicative variable and method names. This is just demonstration.

So if my collection is empty the Collection::first() will return false. Then the getItem call will throw a Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException which won't be catched by the code above.

My question is that how can i catch this exception? I have long chains like this with many getters that can return null. So i prefer this way rather than checking every value for null.

Comment: have you tried catch (\FatalErrorException)

Comment: i've tried catch(Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException) and catch(\ErrorException).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I've found a workaround. I use the property accessor component which throws simple exceptions, not fatal errors.

```
$pa = \Symfony\Component\PropertyAccess\PropertyAccess::createPropertyAccessor();
try {
    $var = $pa->getValue($object, 'collection[0].item.name');
} catch(\Exception $e) {
    $var = null;
}
```

Comment: Using exceptions for logic/control flow is a bad idea. I hope you won't ship code blocks like the one above into any production environment.

Comment: @RaduMurzea Actually its a very common pattern in some languages like Python, where they express it as "It is Easier to Ask for Forgiveness than Permission." (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_syntax_and_semantics#Exceptions)

Answer (score 79):

Use **Throwable** class instead *Exception* class:

```
try {
    $var = $object->getCollection()->first()->getItem()->getName();
} catch(\Throwable $e) {
    $var = null;
    $msg = $e->getMessage();
}
```

Since PHP 7.0 exceptions thrown from fatal and recoverable errors are instances of a new and separate exception class: `Error`. This new `Error` class implements `Throwable` interface, which specifies methods nearly identical to those of `Exception`. Because `Throwable` is higher in hierarchy you can catch with it both, \Error and \Exception.

```
interface Throwable
|- Exception implements Throwable
    |- ...
|- Error implements Throwable
    |- TypeError extends Error
    |- ParseError extends Error
    |- ArithmeticError extends Error
        |- DivisionByZeroError extends ArithmeticError
    |- AssertionError extends Error
```

Comment: I can confirm this solves the issue, but I don't understand why. Symfony's `FatalErrorException` extends `\ErrorException`, which extends `\Exception`. The fact that PHP now has `Error` as a base class doesn't seem relevant since it's not in the inheritance hierarchy for `FatalErrorException`. Can anybody explain?

Comment: @ScottBuchanan I figured out something interesting today. My issue was with Symfony's FatalThrowableError (which also extends ErrorException). I noticed that if you manually throw a FatalThrowableError in an Exception try/catch, it's caught. But I was seeing unhandled errors of this type in the application originating within an Exception try/catch. I'm using the Laravel framework, and I've deduced that the framework caught the unhandled TypeError (an Error, not an Exception) after my handler didn't catch it and wrapped it in a FatalThrowableError.

Answer (score 12):

As you can see [here](http://api.symfony.com/2.7/Symfony/Component/Debug/Exception/FatalErrorException.html), FatalErrorException extends [ErrorException](http://php.net/ErrorException) (PHP) that extends itself php [Exception](http://php.net/manual/en/class.exception.php) class.

Now that you have all this elements, you're ready for next step: as the name of exception says, this is a FatalError (a concept related to PHP and not with Symfony2; in that case they built a wrapper class for this error, maybe for interface purposes).

A PHP fatal error isn't a catchable one so is pretty useless to keep the code that could cause the FatalError, inside a `try ... catch` block

You should check, as a common and good rule, whenever is possible for returned values before try to access them.

## Update

Since I've seen an upvote to my answer *after* PHP7 was released, I would like to caveat that [since PHP7 is possible to catch fatal errors](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.errors.php7.php) so this answer is still valid but only for PHP versions < 7.

Comment: Do you know about a tool that has similar features to the default twig filter?

Comment: @Jumi: what do you mean?

Comment: @Jumi: I know about "default twig filter". What I can't understand here is what do you mean with "a tool"? What tool? A PHP one?

Comment: Yes. A library, a function, something that keeps me away from writing conditions for all getters. Like the symfony property accessor would return an object containing which call fails in the chain.

Comment: I'm not aware of nothing like what you're asing. BTW as I told you, isn't a good practice to skip controls because, eventually, big issues could be found and your code will became shortly unstable

Answer (score 0):

Works for me (PHP 7.0, Symfony 3.0.9):

```
use Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError;
...
try {
    throw new FatalErrorException("something happened!", 0, 1, __FILE__, __LINE__);
} catch (FatalErrorException $e) {
    echo "Caught exception of class: " . get_class($e) . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Output:

`Caught exception of class: Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException`